# Docker Ubuntu build that includes 'apt-get update'

Tags: docker

Here is my docker file :

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install software-properties-common
```

apt-get update takes too much time to run. Is there a ubuntu version that has prerun commands :

`apt-get update` and `apt-get install software-properties-common` instead of `ubuntu:14.04`

Comment: Why don't you create one yourself?

Comment: probably you won't need this because normally docker caches intermediate containers, so if you keep these lines at the beginning of the docker file, docker won't download the updates again.

Comment: @Brian Knight do you mean create a container and deploy to docker hub for re-use ?